# How do Apache IoTDB dividing data partitions in DataRegion cluster settings?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am studying the mechanism of inserting data in cluster environment for Apache IoTDB. I want to ask does IoTDB distribute all the new data to each datanode and then insert it separately into every datanode? I know IoTDB manage data and metadata based on DataRegion settings, but I want to know what specific partition strategy does Apache IoTDB use to determine the amount of data that is distributed to different datanodes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the cluster's capacity of Apache IoTDB remains unchanged, data will be evenly distributed across all nodes to utilize storage and computational resources effectively.During cluster expansion, IoTDB will automatically increase the number of regions to fully exploit the computational resources of all nodes without manual intervention. For the region settings, IoTDB manages data based on data partitions, or DataRegion, which will divide the data from both the sequence and time dimensions.